# Write list of lists to CSV file. Putting sub-lists into individual columns

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I've gathered a list of lists and  I'd like to write each item into a CSV row.

But there are sublists that I would like to put in individual columns.

How can I write the below results into a csv with 2 rows and 4 columns (having `[1,2,3]` in one column).

```
outputcsv=r'C:\Users\out.csv'

results=[[11, 22, 33, [1, 2, 3]], 
         [44, 55, 66, [4, 5, 6]]]

with open(outputcsv, 'w') as f:
    for item in results:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
        f.flush()
```

Comment: Why not use pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
d = [dict(zip(cols, vals)) for vals in results]
pd.DataFrame(d).to_csv('C:\Users\out.csv')
```

In case you want to append to existing csv file, change last line to:

```
pd.DataFrame(d).to_csv('C:\Users\out.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

This is how your dataframe looks:

```
    a   b   c          d
0  11  22  33  [1, 2, 3]
1  44  55  66  [4, 5, 6]
```